# Crystal Report not showing data

Tags: join, crystal-reports

`tblTransaction` doesn't contain any data, so the fields from `tblAccount` and `tblAcctDetails` won't display. How can I get records to display even if there are no matching records in `tblTransaction`?

[image]

Comment: Start your links (joins) from tblAccount and left join to tblTransaction. Note that if you have some report selection conditions on tblTransaction, you have to rewrite those to include null values.

Comment: I've tried all the join type but no luck.

Comment: Do you have some condition on Transdate? Uncheck "Convert NULL values to default" in report options and use report selection formula like `If Not isnull({tblTransaction.Transdate}) Then {tblTransaction.Transdate} > whateverdateyouneed`. Using `Or` in selection formula may not work with NULL values properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the link between `tblTransaction` and `tblAccount` to open Link Options. From here, you can change the Join Type to a Right Outer Join. (Returns all rows from the right table, even if there are no matches in the left table.)

Alternatively you can replace your tables with a SQL command and perform any links or unions manually.

Comment: the link didn't work and I can't produce any sql command that could solve my problem.

Comment: @JogradMahusay You *can* produce a SQL command: Go to the Database Expert, as if you were going to add an existing table, but instead select the Add Command option at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You go through the `UNION ALL` Query for fetching data and try it.

```
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions]
UNION
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions];
```

Comment: How this can solve OP problem? Or how this is even related to OP problem?

Comment: is there a UNION ALL in crystal reports?

Comment: @JogradMahusay Not seen so far.